# How to undo the "install" in compatibility administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10, compatibility, uac

After creating a fix in the Compatibility Administrator, we can go to `File menu` -> `Install` to install it.

My question is how can we undo this and restore the system to the old state?

I believe the `install` makes some changes to registry, I can search the GUID and it's in many places. I don't know if deleting this GUID all over is good idea because there may be other changes too. I hope there is a better way.

Comment: Uninstalll and install without it.

Comment: @Antoniossss I am not sure what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Once we install a shim or shim fix, it is moved to the **installed databases** node in compatibility administrator in the left pane tree. Right-click on the fix and select uninstall!

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/installing-and-uninstalling-custom-compatibility-databases-in-compatibility-administrator#uninstalling-a-custom-database).